# why using recursion using while loop goes in infinite loop but works fine with if condition

Tags: c++

i am working with inorder ,with recursion, but when i use it with while loop,the last call goes in infinite loop, but works fine with if statement.
can someone help what actually happens with while loop and if statement with recursion

```
void tree::inorder(node* r)
{
    node* temp;
    temp = r;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        inorder(temp->getleft());
        cout << "\n\n\t " << temp->getdata();
        inorder(temp->getright());
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `temp` after `temp = r;` so either it doesn't enter the loop at all (`r` is `nullptr`) or it loops forever. Doesn't look like you need the loop at all.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have a `node* head` that has a `nullptr` left node and a `nullptr` right node.

The code above will get into `while (temp != NULL)`.

It will call `inorder(temp->getleft());` on the left node. Because the node is `nullptr` it, won't get into the `while`, in the nested call.

It will call `inorder(temp->getright());` on the right node. Because the node is `nullptr`, it won't get into the `while`, in the nested call.

Then what? It is at the end of the `while`, but `temp` is still pointing to your head node. So, it will go back to the beginning of the `while`. And do that forever.